Unable to find a JDBC driver corresponding to the database kind 'postgresql' for the default
While connecting to postgres db from quarkus application but following error is thrown while building
2024-07-28 01:17:13,026 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor#build threw an exception: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: Unable to find a JDBC driver corresponding to the database kind 'postgresql' for the default datasource (available: ''). Check if it's a typo, otherwise provide a suitable JDBC driver extension, define the driver manually, or disable the JDBC datasource by adding 'quarkus.datasource.jdbc=false' to your configuration if you don't need it.
    at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.resolveDriver(AgroalProcessor.java:371)
    at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.getAggregatedConfigBuildItems(AgroalProcessor.java:345)
    at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.build(AgroalProcessor.java:102)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$3.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:849)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:256)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.doRunWith(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2516)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2495)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:483)

build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-rest'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-arc'
    testImplementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5'
    testImplementation 'io.rest-assured:rest-assured'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-agroal'


    implementation "org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgreDriverVersion}" //postgreDriverVersion=42.7.3

}

application.properties
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.username=postgres
quarkus.datasource.password=admin
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sample
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=3
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=13

code
package com.pruthvi.sample.config;

import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Inject;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

@ApplicationScoped
public class DatabaseConfig {
    @Inject
    DataSource dataSource;

    private Connection connection;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            this.connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to initialize database connection", e);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return this.connection;
    }
}

I am following the official tutorial https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource
And it seems everyting is right?
could someone help to find why this issue is occuring.

I'm guessing that the JDBC driver JAR file for PostgreSQL is not found. How are you configuring the classpath (or module path) ?

I have added it as dependency

As far as I can tell from the description, you are missing
the quarkus-jdbc-postgresql dependency.
Also note that if you add it, you don't need to add the agroal or org.postgresql:postgresql dependencies
